# Anyone know how to change Selenium IDE's background color?

Tags: selenium-ide

It is unusable with a high contrast theme since executed commands appear with bright blue/pink against white text.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure.  But I think the first place to look would be here (Selenium IDE plugins):
http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/plugins.html